# R - Taking column maxes over specific subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large set of data with various indices and such. I would like to change my data from something like this:

```
id  time  var1_t1  var1_t2  var1_t3  var2_t1  var2_t2  var2_t3 
 1     1      1.5       NA       NA      3.3       NA       NA
 1     2       NA      2.5       NA       NA      1.2       NA
 1     3       NA       NA      3.5       NA       NA       .7
```

to something like this:

```
id  time  var1_t1  var1_t2  var1_t3  var2_t1  var2_t2  var2_t3 
 1     1      1.5      2.5      3.5      3.3      1.2       .7
 1     2       NA      2.5       NA       NA      1.2       NA
 1     3       NA       NA      3.5       NA       NA       .7
```

or this:

```
id  time  var1_t1  var1_t2  var1_t3  var2_t1  var2_t2  var2_t3 
 1     1      1.5      2.5      3.5      3.3      1.2       .7
 1     2      1.5      2.5      3.5      3.3      1.2       .7
 1     3      1.5      2.5      3.5      3.3      1.2       .7
```

Except that there are rather more than six columns I need to do this for, and "id' has values other than 1.

I can do this for a single column as follows:

```
for (i in 1:max(df$id) ){
  df[df$id == i & df$time == 1,]$var1_t1 <- max(df[df$id == i,]$var1_t1, 
                                               na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

But that uses a for loop, so it is a terrible idea. And I would have to repeat that line for each column. Is there a way I can do this more elegantly?

Comment: what is `var1` in `df$var1`? what is `var1_t` ? you seem to have some typos in your code, or you do not show some columns. Just `dput(head(df,20))`.

Comment: It looks like that you are replacing your missing values with column-max, not row-max(as in your title). Correct?

Comment: Thank you for noticing those issues: I have edited my title and fixed the errors in my code as presented here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all NA's with the column-wise max value by group of id, you could define a little custom function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x
}
```

And then use your favorite data manipulation functions/package, for example dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_each(funs(f))
```

Or data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, f), by = id]
```